# Checking irreducibility of $3x+6$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$ and $\mathbb Z[x]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Any hint How should I check whether $3x+6$ is irreducible in :
1.) $\mathbb Q[x]$
2.) $\mathbb Z[x]$

Comment: Do you know the definition of irreducible polynomial over a ring?

Comment: If it is reducible, you can factor it as $a(x-b)$ for $a,b\in R$.

Comment: @GitGud I know the general definition of being irreducible:A non-zero element $p$ of a commutative ring R is irreducible if :1.)it is a non-unit ,and 2.)if whenever $p=ab$,then (exactly) one of $a$ and $b$ is unit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: If 
$$
3x+6=p(x)q(x)
$$

is a factoring then clearly 
$$
\deg(p)+\deg(q)=\deg(3x+6)=1
$$

since $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}$ does not have zero divisors.

This imply that one of $p$ and $q$ have degree $0$ while the other
have degree $1$.

Without loss of generality $\deg(p)=0$ and $\deg(q)=1$.

Now - can you see if such factoring exists over $\mathbb{Z}$ ? over
$\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: @patang - Herbert Quain answers add to mine. He gave you a factoring over $\mathbb{Z}$ and claimed it does not exist over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3):

Just check the definitions.

1) You can write $P(x) = 3 \times (x + 2)$, and $3$ is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$ (neither is $x+2)$).

2) Polynomials of degree 1 are irreducible in $\mathbb{k}[X]$, where $\mathbb{k}$ is any field (I suggest you to check why).

Answer (score 1):

Can we write $3x + 6 = 3(x + 2)$ in either ring? Is $3$ or $x+2$ a unit in either ring?